# Ruby madeleine sanity check error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby. I have a gem in project called madeleine (v0.8.0)

When I try to create SnapshotMadeleine object then I still receive 'Sanity check failed for file IO'

```
SnapshotMadeleine.new('tmp/classifier'){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade madeleine version to the newest github version.